# Can multiplexing in Sequel II SMRTcells reduce the coverage?

Tags: rna-seq, ngs, long-reads, pacbio

I would like to have high depth of coverage of the transcriptome, but I need to analyze several tissues. I was suggested to pool all 5 tissue samples in same SMRT 8M cell. Will this result in a smaller coverage when compared to non-multiplex version?

Comment: Well, necessarily multiplexing reduces coverage of each sample. 1M reads / 1 sample > 1M reads / 5 samples (assuming even coverage). Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, all right makes sense. Just another question. Are these reads per base pair or per insert?

Comment: A little unsure what that's asking, but if I understand you to mean library inserts, it will be reads per insert (species of DNA in the library). That should be strongly correlated to genome/transcriptome bases covered, so unless you have some rather wacky insert sizes it will imply reads per base as well.